# Download lower version pod file

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, cocoapods, xcode8

I was working with xcode 8.3.1 and in my current project I would like to integrate below thirdparty :

```
use_frameworks!

  target 'YourAppTargetName' do
     pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.3'
  end
```

but although it was installing latest pod file (which is of version 0.11.4).

Here my issue is I am working with xcode 8.3.1 and latest version of pod file ('SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.4') supports only Xcode 9 and swift 4.So it will be great favour if any one can guide how to install 0.11.3 version pod file of my required framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Besides no version, or a specific one, it is also possible to use logical operators:

- **'> 0.1'** Any version higher than 0.1
- **'>= 0.1'** Version 0.1 and any higher version
- **'< 0.1'** Any version lower than 0.1
- **'<= 0.1'** Version 0.1 and any lower version

> In addition to the logic operators CocoaPods has an optimistic operator ~>:

- **'~> 0.1.2'** Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
- **'~> 0.1'** Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
- **'~> 0'** Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.

the detail info you get in [guides.cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

if you want in below, then use

```
target 'YourAppTargetName' do
 pod 'SQLite.swift', '< 0.11.3'
end
```

and execute `pod install` again from terminal.

Comment: and what about `~>` ?

Comment: @Krunal  **~>** equal and greaterthan, I updated the answer